# Can I return a 500 error from an Apex Controller?

Tags: apex, controller

Can I return a 500 error from an Apex Controller?

```
PageReference success = new PageReference('http://www.google.com');
if(stuffWorked)
  return success;
else{
  return 500 error
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you're trying to use this? There may be a different method that works better with controllers.

Answer (score 1):

The only status codes you're in control of are in `@RestResource` annotated classes. It is not possible to specify return status codes on Visualforce pages or `webservice` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on the situation. There is a [HttpResponse](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm) class, where you can [set response code](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_HttpResponse_setStatus.htm). This should be possible if you're returning a HttpResponse. You don't say exactly how you hope to use, though, so we can't say for certain.

Comment: The header for this class says to: "Use the HttpResponse class to handle the HTTP response returned by the Http class". I'm asking how to return a 500 response from an Apex Controller. I don't believe the HttpResponse class in intended for this use.

Comment: If your controller's methods can return an HttpResponse (e.g. acting as a web service) it could. It depends on your method's signature.